# Is there any data structure in Clojure that allows removing an arbitrary element in O(1) or O(log n)?

Tags: data-structures, clojure

In code, I'm looking for `remove-nth` and `some-coll` that will be O(1) or O(log n) for arbitrarily large collections.

```
(=
  (remove-nth (some-coll "a" "b" "c" "d") 2)
  (some-coll "a" "b" "d"))
```

I'm preferably looking for a solution that uses only the standard library, but I'd be interested in solutions that use external libraries.

Comment: I think you mean *for arbitrarily large collections*, not *for arbitrarily large inputs*.  Removing or constructing `n` items must be  `Omega(n)`, since you have  to work through them one by one.

Comment: @Thumbnail You are absolutely right; that is a more clear way to express what I meant. Changed accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Not in the standard library, but [finger trees](https://github.com/clojure/data.finger-tree) (the original paper introducing them is [here](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/ralf.hinze/publications/FingerTrees.pdf)) get the job done (and are in general awesome functional data structures). You can get O(log n) deletion via O(log n) split and O(log n) concatenation.

```
(defn remove-nth [xs n]
  (let [[left _ right] (ft-split-at xs n)]
    (ft-concat left right)))

(def cdl (apply counted-double-list '[a b c d e f]))

(remove-nth cdl 3)
;; => (a b c e f)
```

An alternative is [RRB-tree based vectors](https://github.com/clojure/core.rrb-vector) (with original paper [here](https://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/169879/files/RMTrees.pdf))
which also offer O(log n) split (via slicing) and concatenation. Plus you get to do this almost transparently atop Clojure's preexisting vectors.

Comment: Just for completeness' sake I'll add that maps support O(log n) deletion of an element and you could always index with integers. Your `remove-nth` suggests though that you're looking for a sequence which I assume means you want other sequence-like behavior (constant time append/linear construction), which finger trees and RRB-trees support.